# any way to add parameters to gdb aliases or create a function?

Tags: gdb, alias

In gdb, I want to create a command that will print out a vector register:

```
print $ymm0.v8_int32
```

ideally, being able to pass in the name of the register, like:

```
pv ymm0
```

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

This is probably close enough:

```
(gdb) p $ymm0.v8_int32
$1 = {199136, 0, 5664, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}

(gdb) define pv
Type commands for definition of "pv".
End with a line saying just "end".
>print $arg0.v8_int32
>end

(gdb) pv $ymm0
$2 = {199136, 0, 5664, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}
```

You can put this into `~/.gdbinit` as:

```
define pv
  print $arg0.v8_int32
end
```

See also [GDB documentation](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Define.html) on user-defined commands.

Comment: Do you even need the `eval`? It seems to work fine with just `print $arg0.v8_int32` for me.

Comment: it doesn't work for me. It says No registers.
pv $ymm0

Comment: @Dov `No registers` is something I'd expect when you are not actually running the program. Does `print $ymm0` work in the same context?

Comment: @EmployedRussian when I print manually it works. The definition does not work.